# Anonymous function not returning the correct string

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, stringbuilder

I have the following piece of code:

```
delegate string CD();
void MyFunction()
{
    stringBuilder.Append((CD)delegate()
    {
        switch(whatever)
        {
            case 1 : return "A";
            ...
            default: return "X";
        }
    });
}
```

But the `stringBuilder` appends text `MyNamespace.MyClass+CD` instead of `A` or `X`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have declared a delegate of type `CD` within your call to `Append` and `ToString()` is called on it which returns the type name by default i.e. "MyNamespace.MyClass+CD".

You need to *invoke* the delegate to get it to evaluate, e.g.:

```
    void MyFunction()
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(((CD)delegate
        {
            switch (whatever)
            {
                case 1:
                    return "A";
                    ...
                default:
                    return "X";
            }
        }).Invoke());
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Because StringBuilder.Append calls ToString on the argument you provided. As far as this is a delegate casted as CD, it returns it's type.

To have the values A or X returned, the delegate has to be invoked. But Append does not expect a delegate and therefore it won't invoke it.